# Merging of duplicate rows that have misspelled variables

Tags: r, merge, dplyr

I'm just learning R (and dplyr), and have what is likely a simple problem, though I have spent hours researching with no answer.  I have two columns, `A` (character) and `B` (integer), in a data frame.

The data frame contains additional rows due to poor spelling in the original data (in column A) and so there are **many** rows that must be collapsed into a single row (whilst also collapsing their integer values (via `sum()`) in column `B`).

For example, there may be three rows that should instead be one:

> CAR.............MPG
>
> Mazda.........5
>
> Mazzda......   2
>
> Mzda.......... 1

Should be

> CAR...........MPG
>
> Mazda........ 8

I'm using `dplyr`, and trying to find the manner in which I can collapse rows with similar characters (e.g. three letters), and pipe back into the original table.

Any thoughts or directions, preferably using base R or dplyr would be appreciated.

Comment: This will help you get an appropriate answer fast. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Using the input `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, use `soundex` or one of the other functions in the [phonics package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=phonics) to derive a key for each CAR and then summarize by key:

```
library(dplyr)
library(phonics)

DF %>% 
  group_by(key = soundex(CAR)) %>%
  summarize(CAR = toString(CAR), MPG = sum(MPG)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-key)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  CAR                   MPG
  <chr>               <int>
1 Mazda, Mazzda, Mzda     8
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "CAR MPG
Mazda 5
Mazzda 2
Mzda 1"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
```